# Estoy confundido con la colocación de “de” y “a”: ¿Por qué se dice "las palabras más difíciles *de* pronunciar" y no *a*?

Tags: gramática, preposiciones

En el vídeo “Las palabras más difíciles de pronunciar en español para los no hispanohablantes” - https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=oCQTnZrwxtE, ¿por qué usa esta frase?

> las palabras más difíciles **de** pronunciar

Yo habría apostado por:

> las palabras más difíciles **a** pronunciar

Esto me confunde siempre.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @pablodf76 pero te voy a ofrecer un truco para recordar: piensa en algo que es fácil de hacer.  No se diría *fácil a hacer* porque "a hacer" no es tan melífluo.

Answer (score 3):

Las preposiciones que corresponden a cada verbo o adjetivo son generalmente arbitrarias y simplemente tienes que aprendértelas de memoria. Se usa *de* + infinitivo con los siguientes adjetivos: *fácil, simple, sencillo*, etc., y sus antónimos: *difícil, complicado, complejo*, etc., y los otros que indican capacidad como *posible* e *imposible*.

Por extensión también se pueden usar adjetivos como *pesado* o *liviano/ligero* con verbos relacionados: algo puede *pesado de levantar* o *liviano de llevar*.

Answer (score 1):

En este caso ambas son correctas incluso podrias usar tambien PARA, en situaciones como esta simplemente es la eleccion de la persona. Diferentes dialectos diferentes elección de palabras. Lo mas común es que se utilice DE.

Answer (score 1):

Pablo tiene razón, claro que hay más adjetivos que llevan "de" en que los hablantes de otros idiomas (inglés p. ej.) esperarían "a", como los que expresan un sentimiento o sensación que produce algo: 
"La película resulta entretenida / desagradable / aburrida / triste / interesante / de ver, pero fue muy divertida de rodar". En otras ocasiones parecidas "para" sería la apropiada: "Javier es muy divertido para salir de copas pero yo no me iría de viaje con él". Quizás porque "salir de copas" es algo mucho más externo a la noción de la experiencia que se tiene de una persona; en los otros casos, el "ver" o "rodar" es consustancial a una película, como "pronunciar" lo es a una palabra.

Decir, "difícil a / para pronunciar", con permiso de Alexander, no lo oirás nunca en España y sospecho que si se oye en alguna parte es por influencia del inglés.  Un profesor que pone deberes a sus alumnos podría decir: "ejercicios a/para entregar mañana..." o "frases a/para traducir" o "palabras a/para pronunciar en la prueba de mañana" etc.: que deben ser entregados, traducidas, etc. Pero eso es otro matiz.

"De" se usa en muchos sentidos en español, debe ser una de nuestras preposiciones favoritas. En este caso indica algo así como "con respecto a / en sentido de / por lo que toca a", como cuando se dice "guapo de cara" o "rápido de lengua". Estas expresiones podrían invertirse como: "de cara guapa", "de lengua rápida", como aquellas también se pueden invertir usando el sustantivo correspondiente al verbo: "difícil de pronunciar" = "de pronunciación difícil"; "ameno de leer" = "de lectura amena". En esta forma invertida se aprecia mejor el sentido de "con respecto a".